# spark streaming and kinesis blank results

Tags: amazon-web-services, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying the wordcount example for SparkStreaming consumer to Kinesis. I have  5 shards in my Kinesis stream and running a local[20] spark streaming consumer process. 
I know there a messages in my Stream as I am able to read them using a simple consumer, but the wordcount example always shows blank rdds in dstream.any suggestions?
The rdd.toArray always prints blank results

```
// Spark Streaming batch interval
Duration batchInterval = new Duration(2000);

// Kinesis checkpoint interval.  Same as batchInterval for this example.
Duration kinesisCheckpointInterval = batchInterval;

JavaStreamingContext ctx = new JavaStreamingContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkKinesis").setMaster("local[20]"), batchInterval);
AmazonKinesisClient kinesisClient =
        new AmazonKinesisClient(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
kinesisClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
int numShards =
        kinesisClient.describeStream(SampleProducer.STREAM_NAME).getStreamDescription().getShards().size();

List<JavaDStream<byte[]>> streamsList = new ArrayList<>(numShards);
for (int i = 0; i < numShards; i++) {
    streamsList.add(
            KinesisUtils.createStream(ctx, "SparkKinesis", SampleProducer.STREAM_NAME, "kinesis.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2).getName(),
                    InitialPositionInStream.TRIM_HORIZON, kinesisCheckpointInterval,
                    StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2())
    );
}

streamsList.get(1).foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    System.out.println(rdd.collect());});
streamsList.get(0).foreachRDD(rdd -> {
    System.out.println("size of rdd" +rdd.toArray());
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kinesis-asl/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaKinesisWordCountASL.java

Comment: If it's the sample from master, I guess your config is wrong. I would guess nobody will be able to help you with the information you provided so far. Try to provide a reproducible sample. No telepathic powers here.

Comment: @maasg added code snippet in question

Comment: @RockSolid did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @summerNight No exactly apparently AWS have loads of conflicts with Kinesis and Spark streaming jars. You need exclude and include multiple jars.. hit and try and with help of aws support can take you through this.

Comment: @summerNight not exactly there are multiple jar version clashes on AWS. You need to hit and try thing and take support from AWS to make it to work